# Trying to create query to export data as csv

Tags: postgresql, csv, export, psql, heidisql

I have a Postgresql table I wish to export as CSV on demand using a query, without superuser.

I tried:

```
COPY myapp_currencyprice to STDOUT WITH (DELIMITER ',', FORMAT CSV, HEADER) \g /tmp/prices.csv
```

But I get a syntax error at "\g"

So I tried:

```
\copy myapp_currencyprice to '/tmp/prices.csv' with (DELIMITER ',', FORMAT CSV, HEADER)
```

But I also get a syntax error at "" from "\copy"

Comment: Where did you run those commands? `\g` and `\copy` **only** work in `psql` as they are not [SQL commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)

Comment: Try doing COPY myapp_currencyprice to /tmp/prices.csv WITH (DELIMITER ',', FORMAT CSV, HEADER)

Answer (score 0):

Running the command that way works only when connection is done through psql.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following in psql.

```
SELECT 1 as one, 2 as two \g /tmp/1.csv
```

then in psql

```
\! cat /tmp/1.csv
```

or you can

```
copy (SELECT 1 as one, 2 as two) to '/tmp/1.csv' with (format csv , delimiter '|');
```

But You can't STDOUT and filename. Because in manual(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html):

```
COPY { table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ] | ( query ) }
    TO { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDOUT }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
```

the Vertical line **|** means:  you must choose one alternative.(source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/notation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I tried to do that but it still said I required superuser.

Comment: @RickLoterio Can you paste the exact error issue.

Comment: You can actually, from docs: "Another way to obtain the same result as \copy ... to is to use the SQL COPY ... TO STDOUT command and terminate it with \g filename or \g |program. Unlike \copy, this method allows the command to span multiple lines; also, variable interpolation and backquote expansion can be used."

Comment: @user3761308 but that way, the content of copy will not be rendered in STDOUT. it will redirected to the filename. I think the post have some permission issue. ...